# Lost data of HTMLEditor textarea on Panel Collapse ExtJS

Tags: javascript, database, extjs3

I'm using Ext 3.4 to make an application with some forms.

I have a form inside aa Ext.panel with the collapse property set to true as I want it to be collapsible.

Data from DataBase is loaded into my form using load methods provided by ExtJS 3.4.

**The problem is that, when the panel "uncollapses" after being collapsed by the user, text area belonging to HTMLEditor widget has been emptied.**

To solve the problem, I could reload data into the form when panel is uncollapsed in some way but I understand this is not the best way (the best way would be not to lose data when collapsing panel).

If anyone has encountered with this problem or anyone knows a way to solve this problem, please, share this information. I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

In Ext JS panel collapse is realized by hiding it's body via style (display, visibility or by offset), and it's definitely not clearing internal panel data after expanding/collapsing by default. Do you use plain Ext JS?

Try to diagnose why this is happening - the best way is to attach debug version of Ext, and step through expand/collapse methods.

You can also check if there are any listeners attached to `beforecollapse`, `collapse`, `beforeexpand`, `expand` events. You can do that by looking into `events` property of panel. For instance: `console.log(panel.events.collapse.listeners)`.

Another thing you can do is to attach handler to `onreset` event, to see if `reset` on form is invoked. Code to attach listener: `formPanel.getForm().el.on('reset', function() { alert('reset'); });`

Comment: I've realized that the problem appears only on textarea belonging to HTMLEditor's contained inside the collapsible panel, so I've modified the post. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

I try many ways to solve this problem but all don't work anyway.

Finally, I look up all the properties of [Ext.panel.Panel](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.panel.Panel.html), and find a property named `collapseMode`. so I add `collapseMode:'header'` to the panel,the data in `htmleditor` is not lost any more.

My code:

```
                xtype: 'panel',
                region: 'south',
                itemId: 'remarkWrap',
                height: 140,
                //style: 'margin-top:10px;',
                layout: 'fit',
                title: 'title',
                collapsible: true,
                plain: true,
                hideMode: 'offsets',
                resizable:{
                    handles:'n',
                    minHeight: 140,
                    maxHeight:500,
                    pinned:true,
                },
                titleCollapse : true,
                collapseMode:'header',
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'htmleditor',
                    itemId: 'remarkInput',
                    labelAlign: 'top',
                    inputAttrTpl: "spellcheck='false'",
                    readOnly : true
                }]
```